# User privacy in WordPress file access

Tags: wordpress, upload, ftp, privacy

Is it possible to create WordPress users that can only view their own uploads and not all of the uploads in the media library? If so, how?

Ultimately, I want to have a password protected interface where I can exchange files with my clients. Because of privacy issues, I do not want clients to be able to view each others files, or see any information about each other. Any ideas on how to make this possible would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that should be able to handle this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-and-document-monitoring/

However, you might be better off switching to Joomla to take advantage of DocMan:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/10958